# React Native ProgressBarAndroid producing a spinner, not a bar

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to get the ProgressBarAndroid to display a horizontal bar, but all I get is a spinner.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<ProgressBarAndroid 
    indeterminate={false} 
    styleAttr="Horizontal"
    progress={.45}
    style={{height: 5}} 
 />
```

I've also fiddled with trying to change the `animating` attribute but it doesn't make any difference.

Version info:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you get the solution???

Answer (score 0):

`ProgressBarAndroid` is now using `ActivityIndicator` to render the loader in RN [0.49.3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ccddbf82d79833702f19d9f6ed1ca23755655187#diff-6e407d4b540029e5d7becdb789c5680c) (See the commit) and it broke the `ProgressBarAndroid` due to some prop mismatches.